# Objectivity and inheritance

Tags: c#

In general, `protected` tells us that the inheriting classes have access to this element

Why is this method not visible in a `Y` class object in this case?

It works only in the case of `public`

```
class Program
{
    class X
    {
        // protected / public
        protected void GetX()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("X");
        }
    }

    class Y : X
    {

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var y = new Y();
        y.GetX(); // Not work

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because only `Y` inherits `X`. `Program` does not. You should read the docs for the keyword again.

Comment: `GetX` is visible _inside_ `Y`, but you calling it from outside

Comment: If I want to call a method from a parent in an inheriting object, do I always have to set it as `public`?

Comment: @ImpoUserC: If you want to call a method from *outside the class* (from "consuming code") then yes, that method has to be public.  If you want to call the method from *inside the class* then it does not.

Comment: There´s no relation between `Program` and `Y`, so - yes - it has to be `public`.

Comment: If I understand your intentions correctly, you can alternatively make the method `internal` so it can be called outside the class from other code in the same project but it won't be accessible from outside the project.

Comment: "_[...] that the inheriting classes have access to this element_" You are right. However, note in your example code it is the `Main` method which is trying to access `GetX()`. Now, is the `Main` method part of / a member of the inheriting class `Y`?

Comment: @Fabulous I have edited the post and there is a different situation. Why does it work?

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one. You can create an other question for the internal keyword.

Answer (score 1):

`protected` just means "visible to all *deriving* classes". A class that is nested within another will not provide its protected members to the containing class. From an inheritance-perspective a nested class has absolutely no effect on the accessability of any member.

Having said this your `Program`-class has absoluetely nothing to do with you `Y`-class and thus can only access its public members. `Y` however can of course access the `protected` mebers from `X`.

EDIT: You may use `internal` instead to indicate that your member should be visible to all types within the same assembly (and thus to `Program` as well), regardless their inheritance-relation to `X`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the method within the derived class. What you are trying is create an instance of the class (Y) and access the protected method. That's not going to be possible. Here is an example...

```
class Program
{
    class X
    {
        // protected / public
        internal void GetX()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("X");
        }
        protected void GetZ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Z");
        }
    }
    class Y : X
    {
        public void GetXZ()
        {
            GetX();// within class, I can access Internal method from base class. 
            GetZ();// within class, I can access Protected method from base class. 
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var y = new Y();
        y.GetX(); // Works
        y.GetZ(); //Does Not Work (Protected method, can't be accessed outside of a derived class)
        y.GetXZ();// Works

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```